# Why use Uri.Builder

Tags: java, android

I am using `StringBuilder` to create `URI` to iterate with JSON Api.

Some people recommend to use `Uri.Builder` for that purpose but can't explain why. Isn't that even redundant?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you are trying to access an API there are libraries that handle it nicely without much work, for example Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: There are lots of big projects without that library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/215853 here is nice explanation. If you are creating Uri, why not use the tool specifically made for it anyways?

Comment: For one, `URI` and `Uri` are different, and `Uri` is seldom used for networking.

Comment: @poss: That is about .net, not java.

Comment: @Axel yes and? the idea behind the question is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're talking about `android.net.Uri` (and not `java.net.URI`), I see 3 reasons:

1. It does URL encoding for you, in case if your HTTP-client/library/whatever doesn't
2. It has convenient methods for adding query params (such as `appendQueryParameter`)
3. It does some validation (but, as documentation says, you should not rely on that)

I would say it is not something you would start holy-war about, but I prefer not using `Uri` as this class is part of Android SDK - this makes your component automatically dependent on Android OS (therefore it's a bit harder to test and maintain).

Comment: war indeed it is. Android code is often very dependent on Android. Would it only be for thread scheduling. (and anyway, `Uri` is not made for networking, but rather for local resources, since the default HTTP client in Android is now `HttpUrlConnection`, which uses `URL` and is plain java).

Comment: `Uri is not made for networking, but rather for local resources` - funny thing is, package called `android.net`

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. It is funny indeed, but I really can't remember when I last used it for actual networking. I find it is more commonly used with `ContentResolver`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html Networking either involves HttuUrlConnection or a higher-level client or a library such as Volley or Retrofit, neither of those use `Uri` in their interfaces

Comment: @njzk2 it does not have to directly accept `Uri`. Usually it is: 1. Build `Uri`; 2. Convert it to `String`. Once again, I do not advocate for this approach - just saw it several times.

Comment: And one another usage for `Uri` - intent filters